# How to get SwiftUI app to use Firebase Functions emulator instead of production?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, google-cloud-functions

So I currently added the Firebase Functions emulator call to my code like so

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFunctions

@main
struct My_Web_App: App {

  init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    Functions.functions().useEmulator(withHost: "http://localhost", port: 5000)
    Functions.functions().useFunctionsEmulator(origin: "http://localhost:5000")

  }

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      MyFirstView()
    }
  }
}
```

But no matter what I do whenever I use

```swift
Functions.functions.httpsCallable("myFunction").call()
```

it does not work. It keeps calling the function that is in production instead of the local function. Can someone please let me know what I may be doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cloud Functions emulator usually starts up on port 5001 (see the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions)).

The following works for me:

```swift
let functions = Functions.functions()
functions.useEmulator(withHost: "localhost", port: 5001)
let helloWorldCallable = functions.httpsCallable("helloWorld")
helloWorldCallable.call { result, error in
  if let error = error as NSError? {
    if error.domain == FunctionsErrorDomain {
      let code = FunctionsErrorCode(rawValue: error.code)
      let message = error.localizedDescription
      let details = error.userInfo[FunctionsErrorDetailsKey]
      print("There was an error when trying to call the function. \n" +
              "Code: \(String(describing: code)) \n" +
              "Message: \(message) \n" +
              "Details: \(String(describing: details))")
    }
  }
    
  if let data = result?.data as? String {
    self.message = data
    self.showResultSheet = true
  }
}
```